# Unable to boot because mounting /boot fails during boot

Tags: boot-issues, systemd-startup

My Raspbian/Debian buster fails booting with

> [ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device /dev/mmcblk0p1.
>
> [DEPEND] Dependency failed for /boot.

If I disable mounting of the `/boot` partition by commenting out the line in fstab, the system boots. I can then re-enable mounting in fstab, and actually mount this partition manually with `mount /boot` without any problems.

Any ideas how to figure out why mounting of /boot fails at boot?

Relevant line in fstab:

> /dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    defaults,ro       0       2

Background: I have created this image using debootstrap. The same approach worked just fine before. I refactored the image creation script, changed some packages, and now this happened. It would be extremely time-consuming to re-do the whole refactoring step-by-step to figure out which change caused this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If that is the contents of fstab you are using some ancient image - and even then it was never mounted ro.

There is actually no reason to mount - except to facilitate firmware updates so mounting ro is futile.

Comment: I wrote this fstab myself ages ago, and it worked until I refactored the debootstrapping script. What would be the recommended fstab entry for /boot then? Have "noauto,rw"?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - no idea why your `fstab` line fails, but FWIW, here's a default RPi `/etc/fstab` from my `buster` system.

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
PARTUUID=6c586e13-01  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
PARTUUID=6c586e13-02  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
```

Your partition UUIDs (`PARTUUID`) will be different than mine; to find yours, run one of the following commands:

```bash
$ blkid
/dev/mmcblk0p1: SEC_TYPE="msdos" UUID="6969-16D1" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="6c586e13-01"
/dev/mmcblk0p2: UUID="f6ea6ef9-68be-479d-b447-5f76391cc02f" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="6c586e13-02"

# --OR--

ls -l /dev/disk/by-partuuid
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Oct 25 14:00 6c586e13-01 -> ../../mmcblk0p1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Oct 25 14:00 6c586e13-02 -> ../../mmcblk0p2
```

Comment: Note: the `PARTUUID` will be different - use `blkid` to find yours